# python delete 2 character in string

Tags: python, string, replace

python search character "x" next step delete this character "x" +  character  "x" -1 postion in string

```
Example x="1. 520 2. 529"
```

I am going to search in `x`  "." and delete "." and number before "." in end I want it look like `x=" 520  529"`

Before I created this topic I only find replace one character for one character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re

re.sub(r'(.\.)', '', a)
```

Where `a` is the string you want to replace in.